# LED Bulb Blinks on One Setting

Tags: electrical

I replaced the 40W R14 bulbs in my china closet with LED 40W R14 bulbs.  The china closet lighting is touch activated and has three settings. The new LED bulbs work fine on the first and second setting but blink on the third(highest) setting. What would cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Are the bulbs you got made for dimmable applications? Unless the LED explicitly says that it is dimmer compatible, it may not always work at different voltages. The characteristics of each make and model of LED are different, so it's a bit of a crap shoot as to whether they'll work at each voltage put out by the dimmer.

Comment: I would also add that the dimmable switches also need to be designed for use with CFL/LED.  Older dimmers won't always work correctly.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Yep. I should have mentioned that. I would recommend finding an LED replacement lighting system for the china closet. There are a few out there that are drop-in replacements for existing cabinet lighting.